# Samsung Galaxy S2 doesn't play music

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, audio

New Samsung Galaxy S2 doesn't play audio files. I tried using different players, but none worked. The track ether plays for 1-3 seconds or mixes different tracks into one. Considering trying to return the phone. Does anybody have solution?

Comment: Which player are you using? Is the issue with some particular player?

Comment: He wrote he *tried using different players*. To me that rather looks like a problem with the related *service* running on the device (yes, AFAIK all players have to run via some "music provider" -- just play an hour music, and then check your battery stats). In which case a factory-reset *might* help, in case something got messed up in that place.